# tensorflow: Something wrong in " tf.gfile.GFile" with "'utf-8' codec can't decode..."

Tags: python, tensorflow

when I run my code ,I get the error like this :

```
File "data2record.py", line 120, in <module>
    run()
  File "data2record.py", line 114, in run
    image_data, shape, bbox, label ,imname= _processing_image(wordbb, imname,coder)
  File "data2record.py", line 64, in _processing_image
    image_data = tf.gfile.GFile(FLAGS.datasets + imname, 'r').read()
  File "/home/tian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 125, in read
    pywrap_tensorflow.ReadFromStream(self._read_buf, length, status))
  File "/home/tian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 93, in _prepare_value
    return compat.as_str_any(val)
  File "/home/tian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 106, in as_str_any
    return as_str(value)
  File "/home/tian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 84, in as_text
    return bytes_or_text.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

And the error line in my code is :

```
...
image_data = tf.gfile.GFile(FLAGS.datasets + imname, 'r').read()
image = coder.decode_jpeg(image_data)
...
```

My tensorflow is 1.3 and python is 3.5.And this code can run in tensorflow 1.0,python 2.7.Why it can't run in tensorflow is 1.3 and python is 3.5?
The code is in datasets/data2record.py in:https://github.com/xiaodiu2010/TextBoxes-TensorFlow
Does someone can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the error says, because it is trying to decode file data into unicode and failing.

Change the line:

`image_data = tf.gfile.GFile(FLAGS.datasets + imname, 'r').read()`

to:

`image_data = tf.gfile.GFile(FLAGS.datasets + imname, 'rb').read()`

To read the file in binary mode. It works in Py2 as str is a byte string by default whereas it is a unicode string in Py3 and therefore needs decoding when file is read in text mode.